# Check for nil in dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a class in my app, where the user inputs values and i set them to an instance of the class, then i upload this data to Database, but i have to convert the class to something the database accepts and i'm converting to dictionary using Mirror Reflection. Some properties in my class can be nil, because by design not all properties are required. But i can't pass nil values to the database.

I have recreated my example is very simplified playground. i didn't set a value for the name property of the class

I tried to check for nil before adding the key, value pair to the dictionary
Below is my code

```
import UIKit

class Color: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var code: Int?
    var shade: String?
}

let cl = Color()

cl.code = 3456
cl.shade = "DARK"

var colorDict = [String: Any]()

for x in Mirror(reflecting: cl).children.makeIterator() {
    if let val = x.value as Any? {
        print(type(of: val))
        colorDict[x.label!] = val
    }
}

print (colorDict)
```

the output in console is as below

```
Optional<String>
Optional<Int>
Optional<String>
["name": nil, "code": Optional(3456), "shade": Optional("DARK")]
```

how can i check for nil values and skip adding that property to the Dictionary

i have tried to loop through the dictionary after i add all values including nils and check for values too but i get the below warning

**Comparing non-optional value of type 'Any' to nil always returns false**

declaring the dictionary as below

```
var colorDict = [String: Any?]()
for x in colorDict {
    if x.value == nil {
        colorDict.removeValue(forKey: x.key)
    }
}
```

removes the warning but it doesn't remove anything.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: you can flat your dictionary anytime, like e.g. `let flattened: [String: Any] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: colorDict.flatMap { return $0.value != nil ? ($0.key, $0.value!) : nil })` or something like that.

Comment: Initialise all values...

Comment: @holex i tried to, flattening my dictionary doesn't remove the nil values.

Comment: @Hend, then try the snippet I have presented above, maybe...?

Comment: @Do2 yes thats what i was planning to do if i couldn't clean up the nil values. But i would really like to solve this as well :)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @do2 Firebase database

Comment: @holex thank you, i did try it, i still have nils

Comment: @Hend, __that is kinda impossible__; could you show your input, please? is it a kinda nested structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way of unwrapping objects of type `Any` that contain optionals is kind of weird but you can check that the values aren't nil in your mirror like this:

```
for x in Mirror(reflecting: cl).children {    
    if case Optional<Any>.some(let val) = x.value {
        print(type(of: val))
        colorDict[x.label!] = val
    }
}
```

Comment: Yess this worked, exactly what i was trying to achieve. Thanks alot !!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this really easily in a one-liner, using `filter`:

```
let dict: [String : Any?] = ["Foo" : 3, "Bar" : nil, "Baz" : "Qux"]
let noNils = dict.filter { $0.value != nil }

print(noNils) // prints ["Foo": Optional(3), "Baz": Optional("Qux")]
```

Comment: unfortunately applying this to my existing dictionary and printing the new no nils still gives me nil values

Comment: Does your dictionary contain other dictionaries or something?

Comment: I only tried this in playgrounds the exact same example i posted in my question.

Answer (score 2):

As i have suggested, initialise all values.

If you decide not to store the nil values you will end up with children that some of them will have 1, some 2 and some 3 nodes, nothing wrong with that, BUT what happens when you go to read them?

You havent shared any info as to how these values will be used by the app, but assuming you have one function to read the properties/nodes of stored colors, it will go to read all 3 :

```
ref.child("colors").child("someSpecificColor").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
 // Get color values
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
  let code = value?["code"] as? String ?? ""
  let shade = value?["shade"] as? String ?? ""
  // ...
  }) { (error) in
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

See the issue?

Comment: I see your point. The values i collect through my app are used to submit an order to the database, retrieving the order is not important now, as i will only be displaying the order number to the end user. But if i wanted to read those values from the database, i would use the "setValueForKeyWithDictionary" function to initialize a variable that has a type of the custom class i am using through the app, given that my Class properties names are the same as my Database node/ key. I am converting my Custom Class object to dictionary just for the database, this dictionary is not used anywhere else.

Comment: You logic is flawed from beginning to end! 1:Why would you write values to the database if you aren't going to use them 2.If you do decide to use them why do extra read and write. ps: Think twice, code once! Good luck!

Comment: I would love to hear your opinion, this is the first app i am building. Users will input order details, these details will be read through a web based admin dashboard which will arrange for dispatch, in future these orders will be read by another app which is used by the employees fulfilling these orders. Concept is similar to how Uber works but its not ride sharing.

Comment: So the order details will be read! If i were you i would either initialise the data, or force the user to fill in all three values. All i can advise you to do is read upon nosql databases pros/cons and how to structure them(firebase has an article), read and write data when necessary and not for the sake of it.

Comment: I will, thank you for your input, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Another 10 from me. This worked well for me with a dictionary like this: `{"TotalCount":0,"RiderCost":null,"NonRiderCost":null,"SaturdayRiderCost":null,"SaturdayNonRiderCost":null},"ShortTermParking":{"TotalCount":0,"Notes":null}}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution :

```
 var colorDict = [String: Any?]()
 for x in Mirror(reflecting: cl).children.makeIterator() {
  if let val = x.value, val != nil {
    print(type(of: val))
    colorDict[x.label!] = val
  }
}
```

Here before to print and add you val, you check if the val is different than nil. As your output suggests in your console log you print :

```
Optional<String>
Optional<Int>
Optional<String>
```

val is an optional. So, if it's nil it won't be added. If not, you enter into the if statement and that's it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still adding nils, i get the same waring "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Any' to nil always returns true" for (val != nil)

Comment: Ok i know why. See my updated answer. Basically i just change the declaration of your colorDict with a type [String: Any?] and withdraw the type cast as Any?. With this val is an Any? type so an optinal and the comparison can be proceed.

Comment: now i get an error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Any'".. the value in (x.value) is what is returned by iterating through the children of the Mirror reflection of my Color class, and i think it is a non optional Any