# Filtering nil values from a dictionary created with Mirror

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, filter

I have a project I'm working on where I need to perform a search using the same terms in `Core Data` and to construct an `URL`. Rather than dump a bunch of code in my DataManager class, I'm attempting to create a separate search term class what will store the elements of the query and construct a `NSCompoundPredicate` and an `URL` when it's initialized.

I'm using `Mirror` to construct a dictionary with keys and values of the class. I'm attempting to filter out non-nil values from the dictionary. I do not understand how to apply solutions elsewhere on the site to my problem.

The only non-optional `vars` for the class are the `Dictionary`, the `URL`, and the `NSCompoundPredicate`. So when the class is initialized, I run a method to populate the dictionary, which in turn is used to set set up a `NSCompoundPredicate` and a `URL`.

Where I'm running into difficulty is filtering out non-nil values from a dictionary:

```
func setNonNilDictionary() {
    // get the keys for the class' properties
    let keys = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.flatMap{$0.label}
    // get the values for the class' properties
    let values = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.flatMap{$0.value}
    // zip them into a dictionary
    var propertyDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values))
    // remove the nil values
    let filteredDict = propertyDict.filter{$0.value != nil}
    nonNilPropertyDict = filteredDict

    print(nonNilPropertyDict)
}
```

When I print the `nonNilPropertyDict`, it's still got ****ing `nil` keys in it. I've looked around at a few different solutions on SO, but I keep running into the same problem regardless of what I try.

What am I missing and how do I fix it?

Here's what my class looks like:

```
class LastSearch: NSObject {

  var startDate: Date?
  var endDate: Date?
  var minMagnitude: Double?
  var maxMagnitude: Double?
  var minLongitude: Double?
  var maxLongitude: Double?
  var minLatitude: Double?
  var maxLatitude: Double?
  var minDepth: Double?
  var maxDepth: Double?

  // methods to create predicate and url reference this dictionary
  var nonNilPropertyDict: Dictionary<String, Any>!

  var url: URL!
  var predicate: NSCompoundPredicate!

  init(startDate: Date?, endDate: Date?,
       minMagnitude: Double?, maxMagnitude: Double?,
       minLongitude: Double?, maxLongitude: Double?,
       minLatitude: Double?, maxLatitude: Double?,
       minDepth: Double?, maxDepth: Double?) {

    super.init()

    // Dates
    self.startDate = startDate
    self.endDate = endDate

    // Magnitude Values
    self.minMagnitude = minMagnitude
    self.maxMagnitude = maxMagnitude

    // Geographic Coordinates
    self.minLongitude = minLongitude
    self.maxLongitude = maxLongitude
    self.minLatitude = minLatitude
    self.maxLatitude = maxLatitude

    // Depth Values
    self.minDepth = minDepth
    self.maxDepth = maxDepth

    self.setNonNilDictionary()
    self.setURL()
    self.setPredicate()

  }

  func setNonNilDictionary() {
    let keys = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.flatMap{$0.label}
    let values = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.flatMap{$0.value}
    let nonNilPropertyDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values))

    print(filtered)
    print(nonNilPropertyDict)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for nil in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393441/check-for-nil-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly compare the children's `value` to nil because it of type `Any` but you can use pattern matching to make sure it isn't nil while iterating through the children:

```
func setNonNilDictionary() {        
    var nonNilProperties = [String: Any]()

    for child in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
        guard let label = child.label else { return }

        if case Optional<Any>.some(let value) = child.value {
            nonNilProperties[label] = value
        }
    }

    nonNilPropertyDict = nonNilProperties
}
```

Comment: it would be better to make it a lazy var instead of adding a method to set its value

Comment: Thank you, Dan! I might implement Leo's mod.

Comment: `lazy var nonNilDictionary: [String: Any] = {
        var dict: [String: Any] = [:]
        for child in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            guard let key = child.label else { continue }
            if case Optional<Any>.some(let value) = child.value {
                dict[key] = value
            }
         }
         return dict
    }()`

Comment: @Adrian even shorter `lazy var nonNilDictionary = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.reduce(into:[:]) { guard case Optional<Any>.some(let value) = $1.value else { return }; $0[$1.label!] = value }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you so much for your input on this. I had something working, but it was generating errors on occasion. Dan's solution and your `lazy` var implementation make it run very smoothly.

Comment: you are welcome. You can also use if instead of guard `lazy var nonNilDictionary = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.reduce(into:[:]) { if case Optional<Any>.some(let value) = $1.value {  $0[$1.label!] = value }`